# Get Field id by field in name Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to MS D364 development. I have a form in aps.net with multiple dropdowns,
the values from these dropdowns are populated with entity fields from D365.

What I need to do is get the id of the field based on the selected value in the dropdown.

Context:

I have a 'Case' entity.

The dropdown is populated with the 'casetypename' field of that entity.

Once a name has been selected and the form is submitted, I want to get the casetypeID based on the casetypename.

This SQL statement best describes what I need to get from D365 in c#

```
select casetypeid from case where casetypename = 'dropdownselection'
```

I hope this is enough detailed info, thanks for any help...

Comment: How have you integrated with D365? With API or package? You can write the required code based on your integration. For ex via API then you need to write the ODATA query like `/cases/$filter=casetypename eq dropdownselection`.

Comment: Integrated with package

Comment: Anyone please ?? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public Guid getCaseTypeId()
        {
            Guid caseTypeId = Guid.Empty;

            QueryByAttribute querybyattribute = new QueryByAttribute("fbcrm_casetype");
            querybyattribute.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fbcrm_casetypeid");

            //  Attribute to query.
            querybyattribute.Attributes.AddRange("fbcrm_name");

            //  Value of queried attribute to return.
            querybyattribute.Values.AddRange(ddCaseType.SelectedItem.Value);

            //  Query passed to service proxy.
            EntityCollection retrieved = getService().RetrieveMultiple(querybyattribute);


            // Set customer id
            foreach (var c in retrieved.Entities)
            {

                caseTypeId = (Guid)c.Attributes["fbcrm_casetypeid"];

            }

            return caseTypeId;


            
        }
```

The above method works for me.